# Downloading jar from github repo fails while using maven compile

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven. Using the instructions mentioned here: http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/hosting-maven-repository-for-third-party-jars-on-git-bitbucketgithub/, I created a github maven repo for third-party jar. I can see the jar (and the corresponding pom) here: https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keyword-extraction/tree/master/repository/com/rapid_i/rapidminer/5.3.006

My pom.xml has these two entries corresponding to the above jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rapid_i</groupId>
    <artifactId>rapidminer</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.006</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wiki-keyword-extraction</id>
        <url>https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keyword-extraction/tree/master/repository/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I do mvn compile, I get the following warning:

Downloading: https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keywordextraction/tree/master/repository/com/rapid_i/rapidminer/5.3.006/rapidminer-5.3.006.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keyword-extraction/tree/master/repository/com/rapid_i/rapidminer/5.3.006/rapidminer-5.
3.006.pom

which further leads to the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DataIndex: Could not resolve dependencies for project DataIndex:DataIndex:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.rapid_i:rapidminer:jar:5.3.006 in wiki-keyword-extraction (https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keyword-extraction/master/repository/) -> [Help 1]

If I manually go to the location https://github.com/sushilmittal/wiki-keywordextraction/tree/master/repository/com/rapid_i/rapidminer/5.3.006/, I can see the files. So I fail to understand why maven is unable to download the jar/pom from that location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First off, please read [this post](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/03/playing-trade-offs-with-maven.html)

Second, using a source control system as a Maven Repository is a *really bad plan*. The recommended thing to do is use a Maven Repository Manager. There are at least three implementations available and there is even an on-line hosting service.

Thirdly, if you insist on following this misguided plan, you need to tell Maven the https path to the *raw* files in the GitHub repo, not the HTML rendering of the file content with line numbers etc